# Passing multiple parameter in url using javascript in PHP Wordpress f/w

Tags: javascript, php, url, parameters

**I wrote the following code in php wordpress to redirect to another page with multiple parameters...**

```
$url = "http://localhost/setupdeal/show-map?prop_type=".$prop_type."&loct_id=".$loct_id."&bhk=".$bhk;

echo '<script>window.location = "'.$url.'";</script>';
```

The output is:
http://localhost/setupdeal/show-map?prop_type=2#038;loct_id=1&bhk=2

But I want the ouput to be like :
http://localhost/setupdeal/show-map?prop_type=2&loct_id=1&bhk=2

What changes i have to make?

Comment: we cannot see localhost links i'm afraid

Comment: we can using severs like xampp. The problem is iam not getting the right url.